# How to connect SQLite Database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

hi
 i want detail steps and programming code to connect database in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class SQLiteTest extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("DataBase.db", 
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        //do the task you want here
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Never forget to close the DB after you complete the task. For accessing Data from Database Use `Cursor`.